# Adapter design pattern explained

Tags: php, adapter

Here's how I understand the adapter design pattern

You have a legacy payment system:

```
class LegacyPaymentSystem {
    public function pay($amount) {
    }
    public function refund() {
    }
}
```

You implement a new payment system:

```
class PaymentSystem {
   public function __construct() { 
   }
   public function payAmount($amount, $currency) {
   }
   public function refund($payment_id) {
   }
}
```

You use an adapter to bridge the two. Sometimes you want to use the old payment system.

```
 class PaymentSystemAdapter extends PaymentSystem {
    public function __construct($legacyPaymentSystem) {
       $this->legacyPaymentSystem = $legacyPaymentSystem;
    }

    public function payAmount($amount, $currency) {
         $this->legacyPaymentSystem->pay($amount);
    }   
}
```

Now the client can do:

```
class Client { 

    public function process($amount, $currency) {
        $legacyPaymentSystem  = new LegacyPaymentSystem();
        $adapter = new PaymentSystemAdapter($legacyPaymentSystem);
        $this->pay($adapter, $amount, $currency);
    }

    public function pay(PaymentSystem $paymentSystem, $amount, $currency) {
        $payementSystem->payAmount($amount, $currency);
    }
}
```

The question I have is, why? Why can't we just call the legacy payment system directly?

Comment: The Adapter Pattern is really only about making the interface of one class compatible with an object or system that was developed under a different contract or model.  The Adapter serves as a layer between two objects, translating the language of one to the other and back again.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, the `Client` should access only `PaymentSystem` and should remain unaware of implementation it is using.

```
class Client { 

    public function process($amount, $currency) {
        $paymentSystem  = lookupPaymentSystem();
        $payementSystem->payAmount($amount, $currency);
    }
}
```

The Adapter pattern allows to hide the nitty-gritty of various implementations by exposing a uniform interface to client, even though underlying implementations  have different interfaces.

It allows you to adhere to a design principle called **Program to interface, not to implementation**

Comment: why do we need the lookupPaymentSystem? why can't we just pass in a paymentsystem variable?

Comment: Well, the method that passes paymentsystem to "process" method, could have invoked the "payAmount".  I mean it seems more correct to have an object and call a method on it from same place - it seems bit weird to pass an object and its parameter to another method and then invoke object's method.   "lookupPaymentSystem" can be thought of as a method that figures out which payment system to use.  Normally, if you are working in a system that allows dependency injection - then paymentSystem would have been injected instead of being looked up